# Feed TCP Socket Data to Tomcat Servlet / HTTP App

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, servlets, tcp

I have a TCP/IP enabled barcode scanner that acts as a TCP Socket server ('pushes' data every time a barcode is scanned).

I also have a HTTPS Web Application served up by a Tomcat Java Servlet (Tomcat 7.0.27 running on a Windows server).

I need to be able to display & process data from the TCP Socket barcode scanner inside the HTTPS Web Application.  I know connecting to a TCP Socket directly from the browser is forbidden. I am also hoping to avoid any 3rd party "plugins" like [Websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify) or [Socket.io](https://socket.io/).

I feel like this should be doable via the Java servlet on Tomcat, but I'm not quite sure where to start:

- When servlet is run, trigger thread that "listens" for socket data from barcode scan.
- When barcode data is received, "push" it to the browser.

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific. This sounds simply like a client/server situation.

Comment: At this point, it's not even clear whether you want the scanner running on the client's machine or the server. If it's on the client, why isn't the client using a barcode-scanner driver that can accept the data and send it somewhere?

Comment: The barcode scanners themselves are TCP/IP socket servers they "push" data over a TCP Socket when a valid barcode is scanned.  I need some way to stream that barcode data to a http web application.  It sounds like I will need some sort of go-between outside of Tomcat that reads the TCP Socket data from the barcode scanners and queues  / converts it to Websockets.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is the wrong tool for listening on raw sockets and certainly not one for pushing and pulling in the way you've imagined.

You need to write a socket server to receive the barcode data. Although it might be an overkill, using Mina or Netty would allow you to quickly write a multithreaded barcode server.

Once your barcode server is running, have it write the data to a queue - you could use a proper queue like Rabbit MQ or with something like Reddis.

You can then use Tomcat as it's intended to service user requests. It can read read from the queue and return the data to the client. Use websockets to instantly display the results back to the client, when new data arrives on the queue.